# Null Reference exception in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning ASP from [Pro Asp.Net MVC5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430265299), when i added a second db and class to the solution i get bug whenever i add DbSet in EFDbContext while loading customer or product page.

Note: product page is working fine, once i delete/move  DbSet from EFDbContext and i checked [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

EFDbContext.cs

```
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete 
{
   public class EFDbContext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

      **public DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }**
   }
}
```

EFProductRepostory.cs

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete 
{
   public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository 
   {
       private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

       public IEnumerable<Product> Products 
       {
          get { return context.Products; }
       }

       public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers
       {
           get { return context.Customers; }
       }
}
```

NinjectDependencyResolver.cs

```
private void AddBindings()
{
    kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
}
```

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial
        Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute.GetHashCode()
       at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
       at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.InternalGetHashCode(T item)
       at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
       at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
       at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
       at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(Type type)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetAttributes>b__3(PropertyInfo pi)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PropertyAttributeConfigurationConvention`1.<.ctor>b__0(ConventionTypeConfiguration ec)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConvention.ApplyCore(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConventionBase.Apply(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Convention.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapComplexType(Type type, Boolean discoverNested)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.MapPrimitiveOrComplexOrEnumProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration, Boolean discoverComplexTypes)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.MapIfNotNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.<>c__DisplayClass14.<MapEntityType>b__e(PropertyMapper m, PropertyInfo p)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements[TStructuralTypeConfiguration](Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Boolean mapDeclaredPropertiesOnly, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClassd.<MapTypes>b__7(Type type)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at ASP._Page_Views_admin_Admin_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Store\SportsStore.WebUI\Views\Admin\Index.cshtml:line 46
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

**Update:**
One last thing to explain. When i moved public DbSet Customers{ get; set; } into another class the admin page loads normally, so repository.Products doesn't return null, i don't know why that happens

```
Source Error:
Line 44:             </tr>
Line 45: 
Line 46:             @foreach (var item in Model)
Line 47:             {
Line 48:                 <tr>
```

Admin/index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

AdminController.cs

```
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public AdminController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(repository.Products);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the line of code that triggers the exception.

Comment: You didn't show code from your controller but my guess is you did not pass a Model to the view from your controller.

Comment: i did passed Model, this page works fine if i deleted DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; } but when i add it repository.Products return null,

Comment: Note to closers: this is not a duplicate of the canonical NullReferenceException question. At the worst, it might be a new case that should be added to the answers to that question.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but do you have a Customers table in your database? When you step through the code, is it the IProductRepository in the controller that is the null reference, or is it the DbSet<Customer> causing the error?

Comment: Yes i have customer table in db with data. it is IProductRepository  that return null, when i move DbSet<Customer> , IProductRepository doesn't return null idk why

Comment: i solved it. one of the attributes i have in the customer db had a null value. Once i filled it with value everything works fine again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was result of having one attribute with null value

```
------------------------------------
| FNAME | LNAME | ........| AVATAR |
------------------------------------
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxxxx |  NULL  |
------------------------------------
```

filling Avatar with value seems to solve it, i never suspected that because there was already some data in the rest of the field